# UI-Router updating history while keeping params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router 1.x and am trying to go to another state while updating the history - but I don't want to lose the params.

So the expected result is that I would move to the next state, and the URL would remain the same, and hitting the back button would take me to the previous state - still with the same URL.

This is my current setup:

```
$stateProvider
.state('parentState', {
  component: 'parentComp',
})
.state('parentState.first', {
  views: {
    first: { component: 'firstComp'},
  }
})
.state('parentState.second', {
  views: {
    first: { component: 'firstComp'},
    second: { component: 'secondComp'},
  }
})
```

I tried this - and it does not work: `$state.go('parentState.second', null, {location:false, params: $stateParams});`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you to go back with windows history:

```
$window.history.back(); using $window services
```

You can also try `$stateChangeSuccess` and keep fromParams in any variable and broadcast if needed:

```
('$stateChangeSuccess', function(ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams)
```